# psycopg2 with flask: how to unstuck InternalError: ignored until end transaction

Tags: flask, psycopg2

I'm using the Flask framework with an ajax calls that returns a table.

```
c= 'SELECT id, type FROM table1 where s_id = %s';
cur.execute(c, (ss,) )
rows = cur.fetchall()
return jsonify(result=rows)
```

- this works, however if there were some error I get a message like this,

> InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until
>   end of transaction block

--
The program is now stuck and unless I restart my flask nothing I do will work.  Is there a way I can check if there is an error and then either rollback or close the cursor and forget the error ever happened?

thanks in advance.

Ahdee

Answer (score -1):

Have a try about [handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), e.g.

```
try:
    something()
except BadError as error:
    do_some_rescue()
```